# In Pandas, how to Shift date index to next calendar date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of financial data that only have data during weekdays.  I want to find the next entry for each row on the next calendar date.  So any Monday would find Tuesday, Tuesday would get Wednesday, BUT Friday would be blank because next day is Saturday which the market is not open.  Same apply to holidays.

If I didn't care about the weekend then a simple shift would do ( Friday would get Monday's data), but since I do care about weekend I need to conditionally shift the entries only by one calendar day.

Example of the data I have, notice some weeks are short week.

```
date    day_of_week day_of_month    day_of_year month_of_year
5/1/2017    0   1   121 5
5/2/2017    1   2   122 5
5/3/2017    2   3   123 5
5/4/2017    3   4   124 5
5/8/2017    0   8   128 5
5/9/2017    1   9   129 5
5/10/2017   2   10  130 5
5/11/2017   3   11  131 5
5/12/2017   4   12  132 5
5/15/2017   0   15  135 5
5/16/2017   1   16  136 5
5/17/2017   2   17  137 5
5/18/2017   3   18  138 5
5/19/2017   4   19  139 5
5/23/2017   1   23  143 5
5/24/2017   2   24  144 5
5/25/2017   3   25  145 5
5/26/2017   4   26  146 5
```

Ideally what I want is this, notice some next_calendarday is blank due it being weekend or holiday.  Theoretically Friday would never have any values since Saturday is never open.

```
date    day_of_week day_of_month    day_of_year month_of_year next_calendarday
5/1/2017    0   1   121 5   5/2/2017
5/2/2017    1   2   122 5   5/3/2017
5/3/2017    2   3   123 5   5/4/2017
5/4/2017    3   4   124 5
5/8/2017    0   8   128 5   5/9/2017
5/9/2017    1   9   129 5   5/10/2017 
5/10/2017   2   10  130 5   5/11/2017 
5/11/2017   3   11  131 5   5/12/2017
5/12/2017   4   12  132 5
5/15/2017   0   15  135 5   5/16/2017
5/16/2017   1   16  136 5   5/17/2017
5/17/2017   2   17  137 5   5/18/2017
5/18/2017   3   18  138 5   5/19/2017
5/19/2017   4   19  139 5
5/23/2017   1   23  143 5   5/24/2017
5/24/2017   2   24  144 5   5/25/2017
5/25/2017   3   25  145 5   5/26/2017
5/26/2017   4   26  146 5
```

Is there anyway to conditionally shift on the index value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need shifting values with set `NaN` if difference of dayofweek is negative:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

s = df['date'].shift(-1)
df['next_calendarday']  = s.mask(s.dt.dayofweek.diff().lt(0))
```

---

```
print (df)
         date  day_of_week  day_of_month  day_of_year  month_of_year  \
0  2017-05-01            0             1          121              5   
1  2017-05-02            1             2          122              5   
2  2017-05-03            2             3          123              5   
3  2017-05-04            3             4          124              5   
4  2017-05-08            0             8          128              5   
5  2017-05-09            1             9          129              5   
6  2017-05-10            2            10          130              5   
7  2017-05-11            3            11          131              5   
8  2017-05-12            4            12          132              5   
9  2017-05-15            0            15          135              5   
10 2017-05-16            1            16          136              5   
11 2017-05-17            2            17          137              5   
12 2017-05-18            3            18          138              5   
13 2017-05-19            4            19          139              5   
14 2017-05-23            1            23          143              5   
15 2017-05-24            2            24          144              5   
16 2017-05-25            3            25          145              5   
17 2017-05-26            4            26          146              5   

   next_calendarday  
0        2017-05-02  
1        2017-05-03  
2        2017-05-04  
3               NaT  
4        2017-05-09  
5        2017-05-10  
6        2017-05-11  
7        2017-05-12  
8               NaT  
9        2017-05-16  
10       2017-05-17  
11       2017-05-18  
12       2017-05-19  
13              NaT  
14       2017-05-24  
15       2017-05-25  
16       2017-05-26  
17              NaT
```

EDIT:

Solution with add 1 day:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

s = df['date'].add(pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))
df['next_calendarday']  = s.where(s.dt.dayofweek.diff(-1).eq(-1))
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the entire row and not just the actual next calendar date?  I basically want to copy the value from the entire row.

Comment: @BillSoftwareEngineer - You think add 1 day? Like in edited answer?

Comment: I got it to work but now I must ask for some help in merging the new row, I will write a separate question for this.

Comment: ok I created the follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67683542/append-all-columns-from-one-row-into-another-row  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it with `pd.DataFrame.apply()`

```py
holidays = ['2017-05-05']
weekend_days = [5, 6]

def find_next_calendardate(date):
    date_str = str(date.date())
    if date_str not in holidays and date.weekday() not in weekend_days:
        return date
    
    return None

df['next_calendardate'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df.date)
    .add(pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))
    .apply(find_next_calendardate)
)
```